# If $H\unlhd SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ and $[SL(2,\mathbb{Z}):H]<\infty$ s.t. $H=\ker(\rho)$, then why is $|\operatorname{Im}(\rho)|<\infty$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

If we have a function $\rho:SL(2,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow GL(d,\mathbb{C})$ where
$m\in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathcal{M}\in GL(d,\mathbb{C})$ and d is given, for example d=3.

And we know that $\rho:s\rightarrow \mathcal{S}$ and $\rho:t\rightarrow\mathcal{T}$ where $s,t,\mathcal{S},\mathcal{T}$ is also given. More precisely $s$ and $t$ are the generators of the $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ group.

\begin{equation}
t=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\qquad\qquad\qquad s=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{gather}
m=s^{\alpha_{1}}t^{\beta_{1}}s^{\alpha{2}}t^{\beta_{2}}...s^{\alpha{n}}t^{\beta_{n}}\\
\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{S}^{\alpha_{1}}\mathcal{T}^{\beta_{1}}\mathcal{S}^{\alpha{2}}\mathcal{T}^{\beta_{2}}...\mathcal{S}^{\alpha{n}}\mathcal{T}^{\beta_{n}}
\end{gather}

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ and it has finite index in $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ and it is the kernel of $\rho$ then why does it mean that the image of $\rho$ also will be finite (i.e. the order of the group)?

Comment: Presumably, you mean $\rho$ is a homomorphism, not just a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it is just because, by the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem), you will have an isomorphism
$$
\bar{\rho} : SL(2,\mathbb{Z})/H \to \text{image of $\rho$}.
$$
The first group is finite, thus so is the second.

I am assuming $\rho$ is a homomorphism with $H = \ker(\rho)$.

Comment: @Hajnus, you're welcome!